# Insufficient free space to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.6 on my laptop (DELL VOSTRO 5590). However, I got stuck with this error. Here is my screenshot of the error I got. I'm so sorry because I do not have enought priority to show it here but link instead.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, there are 3 **free spaces** in my computer memory but they are really small and Ubuntu requires at least 5 Gb to install. I think that my laptop does not share the SSD memory and just support to install ONE OS BIOS, not alongside mode.

So how do I fix this error because I don't want to erase my Windows, it's still important to me. I just want to install alongside.

Comment: Boot into Windows and see how much empty/free space you have left.  If you have about half of windows partition free, you can shrink windows with windows tools and give space for ubuntu.  You will want more than just 5GBs, would try for a minimum of 20GBs or more.

Comment: @crip659 Actually, my laptop has more than 179 Gb free space on Windows but I don't know why my laptop does not want to share the memory

Comment: Should use Windows tools/programs to shrink windows, maybe download a partition manager(google) or use disk management in windows.  I would say around 50GBs up to half of free space.  Before shutting down Windows make sure 'fast start' is turned off.

Comment: Can I suggest an alternative way? Give it a try for Virtual machines (like, VirturalBox). Only thing is you need to have good amount of RAM, like 8 GB. By using virtual machine, you can experience different versions and flavors of Ubuntu.